# Protractor - Manual Boot strapped Angular application - Protractor Binds to Angular despite ignoreSynchronization set

Tags: angularjs, protractor

We have a scenario where Login Page is a Non-Angular page and it brings up the Angular Application after successful login. Post Login, our application is doing a manual boot strapping on document ready state, and associating ng-app to document element.

Our Test Scenario is, Login (doLogin) -> Do Some Transaction (doTransaction)

1. We are using ignoreSynchronization set to true in "OnPrepare" Method. Followed by that, in the test, we did Login actions and synched to an Element in post login page (Expected Conditions).
2. During this time, Angular must be initialized/is In-process of initialization. But Protractor should ignore this process, because of the ignore Flag I set.
3. As a next step, I am clicking on that TransactionElement. From here, everything is supposed to be Angular, and we want Protractor to bind to that. So, we have set ignoreSynchronization to false.

In this whole scenario, immediately after Step 1, I am getting this error stating that "**Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "parent (body) has no injector. this may mean it is not inside ng-app**."

Question is, **ignoreSynchronization** is still true by that time. Why does Protractor report that it is trying to synch, when I set it to ignore? Welcome any ideas on this.

Here is a code snippet.

**OnPrepare Method**

```
onPrepare: function(){
      console.log("**In On Prepare Method**");
      global.sel = browser.driver;
      browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
      }

AngularPage.prototype.doLogin = function(){
                                   this.login.sendKeys(this.user);       
                                   this.password.sendKeys(this.passwd);  
                                   this.goButton.click();
                         browser.wait(this.EC.elementToBeClickable(this.TransactionElement));                                  
                                };

AngularPage.prototype.doTransaction = function(){
                                   browser.wait(this.EC.elementToBeClickable(this.TransactionElement)).then(this.TransactionElement.click());    
                                   browser.ignoreSynchronization = false; 
                                };
```

**Locator of the Transaction Element** - element(by.xpath('//*[@id="global-side-bar"]/ul[1]/li[2]/a/span[1]'));

Comment: If testing the LoginPage isn't very important why not try putting your login steps in the onPrepare as well.  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-do-i-deal-with-my-log-in-page

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would try this out and keep you updated.